# Is my interpretation of `sed -i.bak '/^x /d' "$SOME_FILE"` correct?

Tags: sed

For some reason `sed` has always intimidated me, its syntax is a little odd I suppose. I want to make sure I understand what the following will do.

```
sed -i.bak '/^x /d' "$SOME_FILE"
```

1. This will first make a back up of `$SOME_FILE` at `${SOME_FILE}.bak` (`-i.bak`).
2. Each line in `$SOME_FILE` matching the regular expression "`^x`" (meaning lines starting with an '`x`' followed by a space) will be deleted.

Comment: Yes. It makes sense. Is there some problem with this functionality, or you expect just "Yes" as an answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. From your format, I assume you are using GNU `sed` (other implementations might need a space between the `-i` and the `.bak` and some might not support `-i` at all). Its `-i` works as follows (from `info sed`):

```
-i[SUFFIX]
--in-place[=SUFFIX]
     This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
     `sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
     this file rather than to the standard output.(1).

 This option implies `-s'.

 When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed
 to the output file's original name.  The extension, if supplied,
 is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the
 temporary file, thereby making a backup copy(2)).

 This rule is followed: if the extension doesn't contain a `*',
 then it is appended to the end of the current filename as a
 suffix; if the extension does contain one or more `*' characters,
 then _each_ asterisk is replaced with the current filename.  This
 allows you to add a prefix to the backup file, instead of (or in
 addition to) a suffix, or even to place backup copies of the
 original files into another directory (provided the directory
 already exists).

 If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten
 without making a backup.
```

The `d` command deletes any line on which the previous expression was successful. [Strictly speaking](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03), it deletes the "pattern space", but in simple `sed` scripts that is the line.

Answer (score -2):

`'/^x /d'` The actual space is not required here. Better would be `'/^x\s\d'` which represents the beginning of the string, starting with `x` then whitespace, then a digit.

Comment: Why is the space not needed? `\s` is i) not portable ii) matches any whitespace character. So, for example, it would also match `x\t` and there's no reason to think the OP wants that.

Comment: I guess then it depends on the type of **space** you want. `\t` is a tab character.

Comment: Precisely, so it isn't a space. A space is a specific character, ASCII 32. The `\s` matches tab characters, line feeds (`\n`, although not in `sed`, but for different reasons), vertical tabs (`\v`), form feeds (`\f`), carriage returns (`\r`) and space. In any case, the `/d` is not supposed to be `\d`, that's a `sed` command that means "delete this line".

Comment: @terdon I stand corrected. I was overlooking `sed` and concentrating on the regex.